# Sync Map possibly leading increase in ram and goroutines

Tags: go, synchronization, mutex

Hi here is the code where I make util called as collector

```
import (
    "context"
    "errors"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

type Collector struct {
    keyValMap *sync.Map
}

func (c *Collector) LoadOrWait(key any) (retValue any, availability int, err error) {
    value, status := c.getStatusAndValue(key)

    switch status {
    case 0:
        return nil, 0, nil
    case 1:
        return value, 1, nil
    case 2:
        ctxWithTimeout, _ := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 5 * time.Second)
        for {
            select {
            case <-ctxWithTimeout.Done():
                return nil, 0, errRequestTimeout
            default:
                value, resourceStatus := c.getStatusAndValue(key)
                if resourceStatus == 1 {
                    return value, 1, nil
                }
                time.Sleep(50 * time.Millisecond)
            }
        }
    }

    return nil, 0, errRequestTimeout
}

// Store ...
func (c *Collector) Store(key any, value any) {
    c.keyValMap.Store(key, value)
}

func (c *Collector) getStatusAndValue(key any) (retValue any, availability int) {
    var empty any
    result, loaded := c.keyValMap.LoadOrStore(key, empty)

    if loaded && result != empty {
        return result, 1
    }

    if loaded && result == empty {
        return empty, 2
    }

    return nil, 0
}
```

So the purpose of this util is to act as a cache where similar value is only loaded once but read many times. However when an object of Collector is passed to multiple goroutines I am facing increase in gorotines and ram usage whenever multiple goroutines are trying to use collector cache. Could someone explain if this usage of sync Map is correct. If yes then what might be the cause high number of goroutines / high ram usage

Comment: Could you explain the following points : what do you mean by "value is only loaded once" ? what do you means by "starvation of few goroutines and possible leaks" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For sure, you're facing possible memory leaks due to not calling the cancel func of the newly created `ctxWithTimeout` context. In order to fix this change the line to these:

```golang
ctxWithTimeout, cancelFunc := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), requestTimeout)
defer cancelFunc()
```

Thanks to this, you're always sure to clean up all the resources allocated once the context expires. This should address the issue of the leaks.
About the usage of `sync.Map` seems good to me.
Let me know if this solves your issue or if there is something else to address, thanks!

Comment: Could you elaborate on why cancelFunc is needed in this case. After the timeout LoadOrWait function should return right?

Comment: @MohitJain, ["Canceling the context releases resources associated with it, so code should call cancel as soon as the operations running in this Context complete."](https://pkg.go.dev/context#WithTimeout) You are wasting resources (i.e. memory and/or CPU cycles) if LoadOrWait is called more than once per requestTimeout.

Comment: @Peter : "... or the timer fires". It still remains that the context will remain for the complete timeout duration, rather than at function exit.

Comment: also : since the context is not used as a context and is created from `Background`, a `time.NewTimer()` could be enough

Answer (score 1):

You show the code on the reader side of things, but not the code which does the request (and calls `.Store(key, value)`).

With the code you display :

- the first goroutine which tries to access a given key will store your `empty` value in the map (when executing `c.keyValMap.LoadOrStore(key, empty)`),
- so all goroutines that will come afterwards querying for the same key will enter the "query with timeout" loop -- even if the action that actually runs the request and stores its result in the cache isn't executed.

---

[after your update]

The code for your collector alone seems to be ok regarding resource consumption : I don't see deadlocks or multiplication of goroutines in that code alone.

You should probably look at other places in your code.

Also, if this structure only grows and never shrinks, it is bound to consume more memory. Do audit your program to evaluate how many different keys can live together in your cache and how much memory the cached values can occupy.

Comment: Request will timeout eventually in thay case

Comment: @MohitJain : yes, "fetching from the cache" will eventually time out, after 5 seconds. The fact remains : the *first* goroutine returns immediately and is available for more work, while any of the next goroutine will remain stuck for 5 seconds -- especially if the cache isn't filled within this 5 seconds window. Is that the "startvation" you observe ? your goroutines are not available for work when several of them are waiting for one single result ?

Comment: Number of goroutines are not decreasing in our case. So it seems that goroutines are waiting for lock which they are not able to acquire and hence eventually starve.

Comment: In the scenario you mentioned the goroutine should always complete and should not starve ever since they are freed after 5 secs

Comment: can you please describe what you mean by "starve" ? you pasted the code to your cache structure, you didn't paste the code that creates and dispatches actions among goroutines

Comment: https://go.dev/play/p/rVUSZFM_PLP (your code, with timeout reduced from 5s to 2s)

Comment: Apologies, I have changes the description to reflect actual cause